# Displaylink driver do not work after kernel upgrade

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, displaylink

I updated my kernel to `5.4.0-42-generic`after that my docking station do not work anymore.
So I try to reinstall my drivers and get following message.

```
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.2.14  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 5.2.14 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
ERROR (code 3): Failed to build evdi/5.2.14. Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build/make.log for details...
```

The logs

```
DKMS make.log for evdi-5.2.14 for kernel 5.4.0-42-generic (x86_64)
Thu Jul 23 09:40:00 CEST 2020
make: getcwd: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
DKMS make.log for evdi-5.2.14 for kernel 5.4.0-42-generic (x86_64)
Thu Jul 23 09:40:03 CEST 2020
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build SRCROOT=/var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
make -f ./Makefile syncconfig
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/kconfig syncconfig
  flex -oscripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c -L scripts/kconfig/lexer.l
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
scripts/Makefile.host:9: recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c' failed
make[3]: *** [scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  bison -o scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.c --defines=scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.h -t -l scripts/kconfig/parser.y
/bin/sh: 1: bison: not found
scripts/Makefile.host:17: recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.h' failed
make[3]: *** [scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.h] Error 127
Makefile:594: recipe for target 'syncconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [syncconfig] Error 2
Makefile:704: recipe for target 'include/config/auto.conf.cmd' failed
make[1]: *** [include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Has someone some solution for thie issue?

> EDIT: The driver I installed
> https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: There is a related issue in the github: [DKMS build fails to build evdi module with kernel 5.4.0-42 Ubuntu 18.04 · Issue #215 · DisplayLink/evdi](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/215)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with ubuntu_18.04, kernel 5.4.0 and displaylink driver 5.2
after updating to displaylink driver 5.3.1 it started working again.
apparently 5.3.1 is also for ubuntu 18.04 although not mentioned in the overview page.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem using `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`, kernel version `5.4.0-65-generic`, on a `Toshiba Portégé X30-E-133` with a `Toshiba Dynadock 4K USB 3.0`.

It worked for me using the "Latest Official Driver" (DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu, Ubuntu 20.04, Release: 5.3.1 | 05 May 2020) from the [official DisplayLink website](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu).

The exact file I used was [this](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1576).

Simply download, unzip, make the `.run` file executable, and run it.

A reboot was necessary after the installation and the docking station worked straight away afterwards (screen attached to HDMI port, sound, and USB).

The system already had [version 4.4](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1261) installed but a screen attached to the HDMI port **didn't** show up under Ubuntu's `System Settings -> Display and Monitor`, which was the reason for updating.

I did **not** uninstall the old version in any way before running the installer for the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem as mentioned.

Recent kernel update was definitely the case.
First step you should try to do is to boot ubuntu using previous kernel version.
To do this, go to **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and pick first kernel version under one marked with *.

When system starts, reinstall displaylink drivers like you tried before.

In my case, this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ubuntu 18.04. From one day to the other the docking station didn't work anymore - to be more precise the screens were left blank, but the usb devices were still working. Trying to reinstall the DisplayLink driver for ubuntu 18.04. ended as mentioned above (Failed to build evdi/5.2.14. [...]). Installation of the newest driver for ubuntu 20.04. then worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: You can get the source for the evdi driver, place this in the right location on your machine, and during "sudo make install" for building the kernel, the local source code will be built, and the error is resolved.

Details: I had a similar problem when installing a compilation of the latest kernel tip at the time 6.7.0-rc2, on top of Ubuntu 20.04.03. Specifically, upon execution of the module_install and install portions of the build for the kernel code, errors with the evdi driver appeared.  The system would boot, but only direct hdmi connection would work, not the over-usb-to-display-link setup I prefer.

To solve this, I realized that the evdi driver was being recompiled every time I did a make install on the kernel.  So I searched the hard drive, and found the evdi source code here on my machine: /usr/src/evdi-1.14.1/

So now it was just a question of fixing the source.  You can clone the evdi source code here:

```
git clone https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi
```

And if you start reading the commit logs, the exact flaw I was facing was fixed.  Specifically, some APIs and defines had been removed from the kernel, and this change fixed them.

```
495e8cf Resolve compiler errors when compiling against Linux Kernel 6.6.
```

I copied the code from the modules folder of the evdi project into /usr/src/evdi-1.14.1/ and redid the "sudo make install" on the kernel source tree, and everything got resolved.